# Insert counter in while loop

Tags: python

I wonder how to properly insert a counter in my code. I am just interested in how many iterations it takes to get a gdc > 1. I. e how many times the while loop has run.
How can I fix this? I thought i should put the counter outside the function?

```
import random 
import math
count = 0
# Fu Pollard's Rho algorithm 
#function to calculate (base^exponent)%modulus 
def modular_pow(base, exponent,modulus):
 
    # initialize result 
    result = 1
 
    while (exponent > 0):
     
        # if y is odd, multiply base with result 
        if (exponent & 1):
            result = (result * base) % modulus
 
        # exponent = exponent/2 
        exponent = exponent >> 1
 
        # base = base * base 
        base = (base * base) % modulus
     
    return result

# method to return prime divisor for n 
def PollardRho(n):
    
    # no prime divisor for 1 
    if (n == 1):
        return n
 
    # even number means one of the divisors is 2 
    if (n % 2 == 0):
        return 2
 
    # Intial value x0 = 2, y = x0
    x = 2
    y = x
    # the constant in f(x).
    # Algorithm can be re-run with a different c

    # Set c = 1
    c = 1
    # Initialize candidate divisor (or result) 
    d = 1
 
    # until the prime factor isn't obtained.
    # If n is prime, return n 
    count == 0
    while (d == 1):
        
        count +=1
        
        # Tortoise Move: x(i+1) = f(x(i)) 
        x = (modular_pow(x, 2, n) + c + n)%n
    
        # Hare Move: y(i+1) = f(f(y(i))) 
        y = (modular_pow(y, 2, n) + c + n)%n
        y = (modular_pow(y, 2, n) + c + n)%n
        
        # check gcd of |x-y| and n 
        d = math.gcd(abs(x - y), n)
        
        # retry if the algorithm fails to find prime factor
        # with chosen x and c 
        if (d == n):
            return PollardRho(n)
        
    return d

    
# Driver function 
if __name__ == "__main__":
 
    n = 6310648651   
    print("One of the divisors for", n , "is ",PollardRho(n))
    
print(count)
```

I tried to insert the count variable everywhere but it always gives me error.

Comment: Please update your question with code which has `"the count variable everywhere"` and show us what the error is.

Comment: Did you mean `count = 0` instead of `count == 0`? You are incrementing the count variable in the loop. You just are not doing anything with it after the loop ends. But you have two while loops, so it's not really clear what you mean when you say you want to count how many iterations.

Comment: The `count` that you are trying to increment inside the function is a *local variable*, entirely unrelated to the global variable of the same name.  You would need a `global count` statement inside the function to allow it to modify the variable that you're actually printing.

Comment: quamrana: Ok.  I put in my counter BEFORE and INSIDE the loop. But it says: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/main.py", line 76, in <module>
    print("One of the divisors for", n , "is ",PollardRho(n))
  File "/home/main.py", line 49, in PollardRho
    count == 0
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

Comment: As already said, it should be `count = 0` (an assignment), not `count == 0` (a test).

Comment: Jasonharper: THANKS! That helped. Have a nice day! :)